# Converting h265 video to h264 with ffmpeg results in glitchy visuals with Chromecast

Tags: ffmpeg, screen-casting

I'm having a lot of trouble casting a specific file on my Chromecast. At first it was because it was encoded with H265, which is not supported by my Chromecast device (2nd gen).

I tried changing its encoding from H265 to H264 and it works great when I play it with VLC directly on my computer, but as soon as I cast it on my TV, there are visual patches of color appearing constantly. The sound is fine.

I am able to cast youtube or my chromium screen with no such problem.

I used the following command to convert it from h265 to h264, as found [here]:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Here is the ffprobe from the original video:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'original.mkv':
Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.4 + libmatroska v1.4.5
    creation_time   : 2017-04-26T08:17:18.000000Z
  Duration: 00:11:24.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1152 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Encoded by: ImEverlasting
      BPS             : 997219
      BPS-eng         : 997219
      DURATION        : 00:11:24.601000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:11:24.601000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 16414
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 16414
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 85337214
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 85337214
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 151912
      BPS-eng         : 151912
      DURATION        : 00:11:24.650000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:11:24.650000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 32093
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 32093
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 13000851
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 13000851
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 101
      BPS-eng         : 101
      DURATION        : 00:11:14.239000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:11:14.239000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 243
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 243
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 8531
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 8531
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:3: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 600x882, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      filename        : cover.jpg
      mimetype        : image/jpeg
    Stream #0:4: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1067x600, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      filename        : cover_land.jpg
      mimetype        : image/jpeg
    Stream #0:5: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 120x176, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      filename        : small_cover.jpg
      mimetype        : image/jpeg
    Stream #0:6: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 213x120, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      filename        : small_cover_land.jpg
      mimetype        : image/jpeg
```

And the ffprobe of the converted file:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'converted.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:11:24.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2499 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 10), yuv420p10le(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Encoded by: ImEverlasting
      BPS             : 997219
      BPS-eng         : 997219
      DURATION-eng    : 00:11:24.601000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 16414
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 16414
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 85337214
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 85337214
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 151912
      BPS-eng         : 151912
      DURATION-eng    : 00:11:24.650000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 32093
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 32093
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 13000851
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 13000851
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 101
      BPS-eng         : 101
      DURATION-eng    : 00:11:14.239000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 243
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 243
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 8531
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 8531
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-26 08:17:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.91.100 ssa
```

Any idea as to what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly due to the bit depth of 10 bpc: `yuv420p10le`.

Encode to a standard pixel format of 8 bpc.

```
ffmpeg -i input -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much